# Python loop not running

Tags: python, loops

can anyone help me fix the following code? After the question is asked, and when I reply "yes", the rest of the program doesn't run. No emails are sent.
*Note that I've replaced the login data with 'example' just for this question. The actual code has valid login details*
Edited the variable from "x" to "answer"

```
combo = open("combo.txt", "r")
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
count = str(len(combo.readlines(  )))
print ("There are " + count + " amount of combos")
answer = input("Would you like to run this program?: ")


for line in combo:
    pieces = line.split(":")
    email = pieces[0]
    password = pieces[1]
    if answer == "yes":
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        message = "Dear user, your Spotify account has been hacked\n" + "Your spotify email is: " + email + ", and your password is: " +password + "\n Please change your password ASAP"
        passwordEmail = "example"
        msg['From'] = "example@gmail.com"
        msg['To'] = email
        msg['Subject'] = "Spotify Account Hacked"
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
        server.starttls()
        server.login(msg['From'], passwordEmail)
        server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
```

Comment: `if x == "yes":` - you've not defined `x` anywhere?

Comment: I cant believe Ive made such a silly mistake! thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Ive changed it to answer, but the same result occurs. no email is sent

Comment: Your mistake should have thrown an error...what IDE are you using?

Comment: Im just running it from powershell. I'll run it on PyCharm and see what error pops up

Comment: Most of the code is irrelevant to your problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `combo.readlines()` will read to the end of the file. Saying `for line in combo` finds no lines left to iterate.

Comment: Thanks for this! I added combo.seek(0) to get back to the beginning, and the code works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Robin Zigmond, you haven't declared `x` yet.

A useful thing whilst debugging code that is evidently not functioning, I always find, is to use print statements to check what I believe to be true. In this case, you could check immediately before the `if` statement by doing `print(x)`, to see what the value was - that would have highlighted that the variable didn't exist.

Comment: Can you explain why they didn't get an error for this?